# Solve $f'(x)=f(x)^{2}+4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm rusty in ODEs, so this might be simple..

> Solve 
>   $$f'(x)=f(x)^{2}+4$$

I was able to make a few observations but they don't seem too helpful. First, since $f(x)^{2}+4\geq 4$, we have $f'(x)\geq 4$ everywhere, so in particular $f(x)$ is increasing (this rules out constant functions, for example).

I next considered linear functions. Supposing that $f(x)=ax+b$, then $f'(x)=a$ so by the given condition we must have
$$a=(ax+b)^{2}+4$$
for all $x$. In particular, setting $x=1$ gives 
$$a=(a+b)^{2}+4$$
and setting $x=-1$ gives
$$a=(a-b)^{2}+4$$
In particular this means $a+b=a-b$ so that $b=0$. In this case setting $x=0$ gives $a=4$ so our function would have to be $f(x)=4x$, but this clearly does not satisfy the desired condition. Therefore we can rule out linear functions.

I feel like I'm approaching this the wrong way because I'm only ruling out specific classes of functions, rather than proving any properties that $f$ must have.

Motivation: I am preparing for technical interviews and found this problem [here](https://pbenson.github.io/docs/quantTechnicalQuestions/quantTechnicalQuestions.pdf).

Comment: That is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your DE is $y'=y^2+4$, which is a separable equation, meaning we can "move" all the $y$ terms to one side and the $x$ terms on the other, as follows:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2+4 \implies \frac{1}{y^2+4}dy = dx$$
Integrating yields
$$\int \frac{1}{y^2+4}dy = \int 1dx \implies \frac 12 \arctan(\frac y2)=x+C$$
and so you can solve for $y$:
$$y=2\tan(2x+C)$$

Comment: Great, thanks! I definitely remember seeing this method but haven't had to use it in 10 years or so :)